# What's the word for suicide motivated by positive emotion?

Tags: single-word-requests

Spoilers for JoJo's Bizarre Adventures: Golden Wind

In JoJo, the gang has to deliver a mafia boss's daughter to him safely while they're being hunted down. One of the people helping them is an old man named Pericolo. However, he knows that people are hunting him down, so to ensure the mission's success, he kills himself so that the enemies can't get any evidence out of him.

Before he dies however, he thanks the mafia boss for allowing him to live a long, healthy, wealthy, and happy life.

[![Pericolo commits suicide][1]][1]

Usually, suicide comes from a place of hatred or dissatisfaction for one's life. However, Pericolo committed suicide because he was satisfied with the life he has lived and is ready to leave this world. Is there a word for this?

Example sentence: Pericolo gladly committed [BLANK] to ensure his teammates' safety, because he knew that he lived his life well and was ready to die

Edit: Sacrifice isn't the word I'm really looking for. I'm looking for suicide because one is satisfied with their life and doesn't really need more out of it. For example, Death knocks on an old man's door, and he gladly accepts because he has thoroughly enjoyed his life. This isn't sacrificial

Comment: "to ensure the mission's success..." implies this is a sacrifice. That is the word you would use. You would only use the word 'suicide' if there was no external motivation. Happy or sad, it's still just suicide.

Comment: If you mean an intentional, good death then it's voluntary euthanasia, quite literally.

Comment: "Death knocks on an old man's door, and he gladly accepts" <-- That doesn't sound like suicide to me. It sounds like the way that a natural death is often portrayed in fiction.

Comment: [Hara-kiri is the ritual suicide to restore honor or to avoid capture by an enemy.](https://rephrasely.com/usage/hara-kiri-vs-kamikaze)

Comment: The word is "suicide"

Comment: 'Hey, instead of falling on a sword or whatever, let me just go out happy here…because I'm old and satisfied with everything that's happened up to this point.' Hahaha, OK. I'm thinking you're some young guy…

Comment: Downvoted for the use of the definite article in the question, "What's *the* word...".

Comment: "Usually, suicide comes from a place of hatred"=false

Answer (score 5):

It's a ***[sacrifice](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sacrifice)*** (*self-sacrifice*).

You can say:

> After living a long happy life, Pericolo gladly ***sacrificed himself*** to ensure his teammates' safety.

If you find it too ambiguous, you can say ***sacrificed his life***.

Note that there is the idiom:

> ***make the ultimate/supreme sacrifice***
> idiom   formal
> to die while fighting for a principle ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-the-ultimate-supreme-sacrifice))

It's not a single word, but this article about ***Altruistic suicide*** (also called *benevolent suicide*) from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruistic_suicide#:%7E:text=Altruistic%20suicide%20is%20the%20sacrifice,sake%20of%20the%20greater%20good.) may be helpful.

Comment: Sacrifice isn't the word I'm really looking for. I'm looking for suicide because one is satisfied with their life and doesn't really need more out of it. For example, Death knocks on an old man's door, and he gladly accepts because he has thoroughly enjoyed his life. This isn't sacrificial

Comment: Well, in your sample sentence, you did say _**to ensure his teammates' safety**_. That is sacrificial.

Comment: Edited my sample sentence, is my intent clearer now?

Comment: @SomeGuy 'sacrifice' -is- the word you're looking for. The soldier who jumps on a grenade to save his comrades, the parent on the Titanic who pushes their kid onto the life raft, they are sacrificing themselves. In fact that's so much the way to say it, that it would be strange to call these two instances 'suicide' in any way.

Comment: @SomeGuy Well, by your edit, you've invalidated my answer...

Comment: *"he kills himself so that the enemies can't get any evidence out of him"* that is self-sacrifice or martyrdom. It is not just "I am satisfied with life, now I can go". It's bad form to change the question once answers have been posted. The sentence: "Pericolo gladly sacrified himself to ensure his teammates' safety, **and** because he knew that he lived his life well and was ready to die."

Answer (score 0):

French sociologist Emile Durkheim in his classic book *[Suicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_(Durkheim_book))* described four types of suicide. Because he was a sociologist he was interested in how society causes suicide. His four types are known in English as:

1. Egoistic suicide, where you feel isolated and detached from society
2. Altruistic suicide, done for the benefit of society
3. Anomic suicide, where the individual feels unmoored by a society undergoing sudden, unpredictable change
4. Fatalistic suicide, where society is so regulated and controlled that you would rather die than live

The OP's case is an example of **altruistic suicide**, done for the benefit of others without an personal dissatisfaction with that society.